Code working with only 1 game object instead of 2
So im creating a tcg, where you currently control both players. Im in process of adding drawing cards, which i do with right click in here
if (isPlayerOnTurn) 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) 
    {
        currentDeck[0].AddCardToHand();
        OnHandChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    } 
}

the process looks like this: currentDeck is a list of class BaseCard which is a script that all cards have contaning all card that are not in hand, field ect., and AddCardToHand is script that just moves the card form list is currently in into the hand. OnHandChanged is for visualization.
This works fine however. The problem is in isPlayerOnTurn defined in Player (public bool isPlayerOnTurn;) and has its value assinged in inspector. In scene there are 2 GO with Player script P1 and P2, with their own lists and all. But for some reason this works only with P2, working with P1 only if I disable P2 before starting. It doesn't work if i set isPlayerOnTurn to true on P1 and to false on P2.
I dubuged just to check if the bools have right values, checked if both classes are reciving inputs and even changed the order in hierarchy, but i really dont know where is the problem.

It doesn't look to me like we have enough context to help you troubleshoot this issue. We can't see where isPlayerOnTurn is defined or how its value is assigned. Try to edit your question to walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. A reader following your instructions should be able to start from a new, empty project, and arrive at a simple scene that reproduces the issue you're having, with as little extraneous content as possible. Once we can reproduce exactly what you're seeing, we can test solutions to be sure they'll work for you.

We're looking for a much more thorough edit than this, with the complete code file needed to reproduce the issue.
